# Best way to link related Posts?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I recently was looking into how to trim/round TimeDates for C# and found a plethora of questions answering the same thing.  I agree that StackOverflow is much better than many boards about eliminating/automatically linking questions like this, but the problem still exists.

Not only were there multiple posts, but I also found that some of the questions dealt with a more nuanced problem (preserving the TimeDate.Kind) while others completely ignored this aspect.

So what I'm asking is: is there any way for me to be able to flag to someone (an admin, users themselves) that the questions are related and flag to multiple users that they have a minor bug in the code?

Specific examples of related questions that aren't necessarily tagged to each other:

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152774/is-there-a-better-way-to-trim-a-datetime-to-a-specific-precision)
[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499479/how-to-round-off-hours-based-on-minuteshours0-if-min30-hours1-otherwise/2906684#2906684)
[Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393696/c-rounding-datetime-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hit the `flag` button (next to edit and close) to flag a moderator, then explain briefly what's up.

You can comment any user by adding a comment with at least the first three letters of his name prepended by an ampersand, like @CrimsonX.

I've put a vote-to-close as duplicate for the cases two and three.

Comment: @Comment only works if the person in question has either commented or edited the post. It's also unnecessary for the author of the post as they automatically get notified. Which is actually pretty good for notifying two people at once, if the comment stream includes a second person on your target list.

Comment: flagging sounds like a good idea, and thanks for the clarification for the @Comment!

Comment: It would be great if SO could recognize internal links and ask the linker to give a "rel" like duplicate or see also!

Answer (score 0):

You can also put a link to a related question in your answer or comment.
like
[linking related questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89806/how-do-i-link-a-question-to-another-question)