# How do I link a question to another question?

Tags: support, questions, hyperlinks

I have read the FAQ, couldn't find it there.

Comment: don't worry about that my rep isn't sufficient yet, I just want to know how it is done

Comment: I will read Best way to link related Posts (ty) for generating 'Related' stackoverflow team!

Comment: Find a question, copy the link from your browser's address bar, and paste it into your answer. Where's the confusing part?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38882/link-from-question-to-duplicates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you got 50 reputation (1 here on meta), you can comment the link as a comment to any question (you can always do on your own question), and it would be linked at "Linked" column on the right side of the question.