# Shortly link to another question on the same site?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

There should be a shorthand for linking to other questions, like in Redmine (An issue tracking system).

E.g., when I'm on this site, posting

> `#89806`

should yield the same as

> `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89806`

yielding this:

> [How do I link a question to another question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89806)

or it should be escapable like:

> `[questions#89806]`

Benefit: Readable editor window plus smaller databases ;)

Comment: How is a number more readable than [auto-linked raw URLs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/69483#69483)?

Comment: Where? In questions? Answers? Comments?

Comment: I don't mind auto-links at all, but while editing a post, the markup editor becomes rather crowded with lengthy URLs. Going to edit the question, though. Here: Not necessarily, yes, yes please

Comment: I don't feel the benefit (if any) makes up for a Markdown exception/enhancement/oddity. (Remember [the data dumps](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/)?)

Comment: Edited. Similar shorthands are available for links to tags, meta, users, but not to questions.

Comment: Note that http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89806 also works, and is probably as short as you are going to get while still working across SE sites.

Comment: Shorthands for users are new to me, but others, [even those in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) use a readable format. Hence, a Markdown renderer that does not know them, still renders them in a readable way, I feel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others pointed out, there is a short form:

`http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107876/shortly-link-to-another-question-on-the-same-site`

to

`http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107876`

The link item under the question will give you this shortened form.

(This also works for users, by the way)

Comment: With *This also works for users* you only mean that `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/1` redirects to the full URL, right? True: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/1 Or should it also render as "Jeff Atwood"? (It does not show the real name in the preview, [nor in the sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/74750#74750).) As an aside: the "link" item under the question gives one [a referral link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/), which is a bit longer than the shortest link.